# Entering Ukraine as a Ukrainian born, naturalised British citizen

Tags: passports, dual-nationality, uk-citizens, ukraine, ukrainian-citizens

I left Ukraine when I was 8, moved to the UK in 2005.

I was born in Ukraine but permanently reside in the UK, have British Citizenship and a British Passport.

Will I have any problems with going back to Ukraine? I have never had a Ukrainian passport. My mum is convinced there will be problems at the border because Ukraine does not recognise dual citizenship. She is worried that I will not be able to leave Ukraine on my return journey back to the UK. Especially because I am 22, male and have not registered on anything in Ukraine, including military service (as I do not live there). I don’t think I have officially declared that I am a permanent resident in the UK either - but I’m not sure if I have to do that?

Has anyone ever had any problems with traveling there and back? Especially my age. What should I expect?

Edit:

1. I gained British Citizenship a few months ago, when I was 21 (before my birthday).
2. I do not have a Ukrainian passport at all.
3. I had a child travel document but that expired in 2008.
4. My birth certificate is Ukrainian.
5. Both of my birth parents are Ukrainian and held Ukrainian citizenship when I was born.
6. My British Passport lists my birthplace as a Ukrainian city.

Comment: At what age did you gain British citizenship?

Comment: @mjeffryes At 21, a few months ago.

Comment: [Wikipedia's article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukrainian_nationality_law) states that "Automatic loss of Ukrainian citizenship occurs in the event an adult Ukrainian citizen voluntarily acquires a foreign nationality".

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Sadly I don’t really trust the article as the source seems to contain information from the law on citizenship from 2012. I’m not sure if it is still the same to this day

Comment: More to the point, why do you believe you might have Ukrainian citizenship?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Because as far as I am aware, Ukraine does not recognise dual citizenship. I was born in Ukraine and therefore hold Ukrainian citizenship. I have never renounced it. If I understand the articles I read online in English correctly, if you hold dual nationalities then Ukraine would only consider you as a Ukrainian citizen, while you are in Ukraine - but I have no way of confirming this as I am not able to read Ukrainian or find the latest legislations and or laws regarding this. The law seems to be very vague and I was looking to see if anyone could provide me with some clarity

Comment: AFAIK Ukraine does not have jus soli citizenship, so merely being born there is not sufficient for citizenship.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Even if I lived there until the age of 8?

Comment: Were your parents stateless, then? There's just no information here that would indicate you might have Ukrainian citizenship at all.

Comment: @MichaelHampton presumably the parents were Ukrainian citizens at the time of OP's birth.

Comment: @phoog That seems unlikely, as he would have mentioned it by now after having been asked repeatedly. Not to mention he would presumably have had a passport as a child instead of a travel document.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I don't see any questions about the parents' citizenship except for the one to which I responded (and which OP hasn't yet seen).  What have I overlooked?  Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukrainian_Travel_Document_of_a_Child.  It's essentially a passport with an unusual document title.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Both of my birth parents are Ukrainian and held Ukrainian citizenship when I was born. I moved to the UK as a Ukrainian citizen, when I was 8 years old, using my child travel document. I've never owned a passport until applying for my British passport.

Comment: @nopassport1 Out of curiosity, what nationality did you specify when you applied for British citizenship? Did you say you were Ukrainian? Stateless?

Comment: @kiradotee Ukrainian

Comment: You would be entering and leaving Ukraine as a British сitizen, so at no point of your stay in Ukraine and border crossing you are going to be questioned about your possible Ukrainian citizenship. There is no trace to your Ukrainian roots, even to birth certificate details. For the record, Ukrainian citizens of the age of 22 are leaving Ukraine on their trips without problems given that they hold valid passports.

Comment: "If I understand the articles I read online in English correctly, if you hold dual nationalities then Ukraine would only consider you as a Ukrainian citizen, while you are in Ukraine" this is about right formally but in your case there is nothing connecting you to Ukrainian citizenship that can possibly play out. Border service does not even deal with information that there was someone with "similar" name and DOB who could possibly be a Ukrainian entering with another travel document. This data exist but it would only matter if you apply for national passport or a copy of birth certificate.

Comment: @RomanR. "but in your case there is nothing connecting you to Ukrainian citizenship that can possibly play out" - Even if it lists my birthplace as a Ukrainian city in my British Passport?

Comment: It's a good argument and so a Border Service officer might have a suspicion that you might also be holding Ukrainian citizenship as well. Still it does not make you Ukrainian and it's not Border Service business to prove this or do anything with this otherwise.

Comment: If you was born in Ukraine and your parents respective obtained certificate of birth here, your British citizenship does not invalidate Ukrainian. Technically you could apply for national passport, pay a fine for not doing this in time, register your place of living  - however it's what you would need if you wanted to consume services as a citizen of Ukraine. But if you don't need this and you hold another passport, then noone really cares that you are technically Ukrainian as well. You will find no case that "Ukrainian attempted to enter the country presenting another passport".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am an Ukrainian citizen.

I didn't have such an experience nor people I know had but I can refer to the legal document.

[The Law of Ukraine "On Citizenship of Ukraine"](https://zakon2.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/2235-14?lang=en) regulates your question.

There is an article 2(стаття 2) in this law, which constitutes that in Ukraine there is no such thing as multiple citizenship, you must not and cannot have a citizenship in order to acquire Ukrainian one.

In article 19(стаття 19), it is said that effectively you are losing Ukrainian citizenship the moment you acquire a citizenship of other country if it is done voluntary and you are an adult(your age is above 18). Thus you, effectively, was a Ukrainian citizen by birthplace(cause you have a birth certificate) until you have accepted the British citizenship. Another sidenote, it wouldn't be considered voluntary if you didn't receive a document that justifies that.

Even if you had Ukrainian citizenship, it would have been much much tougher to enter EU from UK with Ukrainian citizenship than Ukraine itself and back. Ukraine ain't some African country, if you are Ukrainian in Ukraine you can leave the country if you have required documents for leaving to some country(e.g visa to UK) as all civilized countries do.

That said, you are just another British citizen which enters Ukraine. 
Given you didn't commit any crimes in Ukraine which remained unanswered AND you have a valid type of visa of your choice with all required prerequisites and conditions met - you should be absolutely fine.

Comment: The OP's concern seems to be that Ukraine would not recognize his (implicit) renunciation of citizenship if they consider it to be a draft-dodging ploy. Or formally they might recognize him as not-a-citizen, but still consider it an offense within their criminal jurisdiction to renounce citizenship while eligible for the draft without having served.

Comment: Also, the "some African country" quip sounds pretty offensive. The country that seems to be most famous for enforcing conscription on ex-citizens who left the country at a young age is South Korea, which is farther from Africa than Ukraine is.

Comment: Like I said, I didn't have such an experience and I am just refering to legal documents. The official law states that a citizenship is dismissed if you have commited actions that constitute such a dismissal.

Comment: Actually, its more complicated than that. There's plenty of Ukrainian dual citizens due to how the law is worded.

Comment: @JonathanReez This is very true. But once again, I just tried to answer this from a legal point of view, real-life applications of this law due to myriad of other factors to this particular matter might be different from what I wrote.

Comment: "Ukraine ain't some African country, if you are Ukrainian in Ukraine you can leave the country if you have required documents for leaving to some country(e.g visa to UK) as all civilized countries do" **Wrong.** I saw a US/Israeli dual citizen detained leaving the country, and a US Citizen of ex-Israeli parents warned that he needed to obtain an Israeli passport even though he was born in the USA. IN fact, Army permission to leave is checked for Israeli nations at the airport. I've read a similar story about Greece, but didn't see it first-hand.

Comment: I don't think you give correct interpretation of article 19 in the body of your answer. It says that the date of stopping Ukrainian citizenship is effectively the date of respective presidential Decree and people who explicitly apply to stop their citizenship wait for this decree forever, still being citizens.